# Youtube video updated date

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api

In the version 2 of the youtube api, there was an [updated tag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_updated) that would give me the time the video was last updated. In [version3 of the api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) I can't find the tag that represent this value. Is it possible that they removed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an equivalent field in V3 yet, but it could be implemented in future.